# Puppet parameterized classes and changing parameters

Tags: class, parameterized, puppet

I am trying to understand Puppet parameterized classes. I have a parameterized class defined this way:

```
class defaults(
  $no_samba = 'FALSE'
)
{
  if ($no_samba =~ /TRUE/) {
    notify { "will not install samba": } ;
  } else {
    # install samba here
  }

  # More server install tasks here...
}
```

Furthermore, I define a basenode as follows:

```
node basenode
{
  class {'defaults':
    no_samba => 'FALSE',
  }
}
```

and then I instantiate a server:

```
node myserver1 inherits basenode {
  Class['defaults'] { no_samba => 'TRUE' }
}
```

However, this does not work. The myserver1 node does not show the notify message indicating that samba will not be installed.

Comment: To whoever is reading this years later: Puppet supports boolean values. No need to check strings with RegEx. Also the understandability is always better if you're using positive flags, e.g. `use_samba = true` instead of `no_samba = false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my non-typo answer - I think you're running into http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/7890

Here's a code sample where I tweaked your code to get the effect you're looking for, based on the rewritten example in the ticket:

```
class defaults(
  $no_samba = 'FALSE'
)
{

  notify {"no_samba_hack" :
    message => "$no_samba";
  }

  if ($no_samba =~ /TRUE/) {
    notify { "will not install samba": }
  } else {
    # install samba here
  }

  # More server install tasks here...
}

class basenode($no_samba="FALSE") {
  class {defaults: no_samba => $no_samba}
}

node yourserver {

  class { 'basenode' : no_samba => 'TRUE'}

}
```

When I run that with 'puppet apply sample.pp' with puppet 2.7.11 on Ubuntu 12.04, I get the following output:

```
notice: will not install samba
notice: /Stage[main]/Defaults/Notify[will not install samba]/message: defined 'message' as 'will not install samba'
notice: TRUE
notice: /Stage[main]/Defaults/Notify[no_samba_hack]/message: defined 'message' as 'TRUE'
notice: Finished catalog run in 0.05 seconds
```

Comment: In my question `basenode` is a node not a class. Does that make a difference to your answer?

Comment: No, In my answer I switched it from a node to class since puppet doesn't allow parametrized nodes.

Comment: Since I want `basenode` to be a node, how would I use your work-around in my case?

Comment: I don't know, but I would recommend against using node-based inheritance.  As the number of nodes you're managing with puppet gets larger, you may eventually want to migrate to an ENC (http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html), and if you're nodes are doing anything other than including classes, that'll make the migration more difficult.  I don't think there's anything you can do with node-based inheritance that can't be handled by including a class which inherits from other classes.

Answer (score 1):

Was samba installed on myserver1, and/or did any of the other server install tasks get triggered ?  If only the notify message wasn't printed, then it may really be a problem with  [notify type](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.7.6/type.html#notify) versus the [notice function](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/function.html#notice).

Notify should look like "notify{"i have curly brackets and a trailing colon":}

Notice is called like a function: notice("i use parenthesis")

Try changing 'notify' to 'notice' and see if it works.  You may also want to check the puppet syntax with 'puppet parser validate default.pp' (assuming your default class is in default.pp)

Comment: I made a mistake typing in the original code into my question but I have now corrected the notify syntax error. That is not the problem. The issue has something to do with my not understanding how to use a parameterized class.

Comment: Something else to check - during instantiation 'true' is being passed in, but the conditional is matching against 'TRUE', so it may be a case mismatching issue.  If that's still not it, check the puppetmaster and client logs for error messages.

Comment: Sorry: that was another typo (which I have now fixed). I will look into the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has to do with scope. It looks like you're creating the 'default' class in the base node and then setting a resource default for the 'default' class after the fact in something that inherits that basenode.

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html

"Defaults are not global — they only affect the current scope and scopes below the current one."

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example:

```
class apache-setup {
  class { 'apache':
    mpm_module => 'prefork',
  }
}

include apache-setup
```

Or:

```
class { '::mysql::server':
  config_file => '/etc/my.cnf',
  root_password    => 'root', # Sets MySQL root password.
  override_options => {
    'mysqld' => {
      'max_connections' => '512',
      'max_allowed_packet' => '256M',
      'log' => 'ON',
      'log_slow_queries' => 'ON',
      'general_log' => 'ON',
      'wait_timeout' => '28800',
    }
  }
}
```